# Safari border margin error

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website, i have created a tab, with borders around the content. Everything shows fine in Chrome but i am having a problem with Safari. The left and right side borders are outset in safari, the are not in the margins i want to be, i want them to be inline with the tabs.

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel {
     padding: 1em 0.4em;
     background: none;
     border: 1px solid rgba(216, 216, 216, 0.55);
     border-top: none;
     margin-top: -5px;
     margin-left: 2px;
     margin-right: 4px; 
 }
```

Can anyone help?

Anyone? Its the margin-right: 4px that is the problem. If i change it to 11px it shows fine in Safari but then it goes offset it Chrome. Please help

Comment: Anyone? Its the margin-right: 4px that is the problem. If i change it to 11px it shows fine in Safari but then it goes offset it Chrome. Please help

Comment: Can you post it in JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Without JSFiddle example I am working blind, but you try this:

CSS:

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel {
    display: inline;
    margin: 5px 4px 0px 2px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(216, 216, 216, 0.55);
    border-top: none;
    background: none;
}
```